# Tool like PyInstaller but without the bundling?

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller, setuptools

I have a GUI app that I would like to distribute using PyInstaller, but it can sometimes be difficult to get PyInstaller apps to run due to complex imports and/or dlls. It would be nice if there were a backup options where we could create a launcher that just relies on a local Python installation, where we can be more confident that the dependencies are in order. [Setuptools claims to support](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/setuptools.html?highlight=exe#building-and-distributing-packages-with-setuptools) something similar, but it is based on the deprecated Easy-Install, and is not supported by pip.

This may seem like a trivial task, but here are the main three things I'd like this tool to do:

- Create an OS appropriate executable launcher (Windows, Mac or Linux) in a user-specified directory
- The launcher should activate the appropriate Python environment if necessary
- Copy any application config files that the user might need to change to the application directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like [Pyshortcuts](https://github.com/newville/pyshortcuts) can handle the first two requirements. Copying of config files would then need to be handled by either the application or as part of an install script.